# jquery show-hide not working for value !=

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I am trying to show and hide content based on value in select field.

I want to only display content in Div 1 if the value for a select field is 'United States'. And only display content in Div 2 if the value is any other country EXCEPT 'United States. But the 2nd part is not working.

Here is what I have so far. This will display Div 1 if United States selected, but not Div 2 if I select another country.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
            $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=='United States'){
                    $(".rest1").show();
                    $(".rest2").hide();
             
                }
                 if($(this).attr("value")!='United States'){
                    $(".rest2").show();
                    $(".rest1").hide();
                   
                }
                
            });
        }).change();
    });
</script>
```

The following works if I specify another country, but I need Div 2 to display for ALL countries except 'United States'.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select").change(function(){
            $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=='United States'){
                    $(".rest1").show();
                    $(".rest2").hide();
             
                }
                 if($(this).attr("value")=='Austria'){
                    $(".rest2").show();
                    $(".rest1").hide();
                   
                }
                
            });
        }).change();
    });
</script>
```

What am I missing?

David Thomas - Here is more of the html. I hope this is enough:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("value") == 'United States') {
        $(".rest1").show();
        $(".rest2").hide();

      }
      if ($(this).attr("value") != 'United States') {
        $(".rest2").show();
        $(".rest1").hide();
      }

    });
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.rest1,
.rest2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="country" class="form-label">Country <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
  <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control" {if option:checked}checked{/if}>
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="Austria" {if country=="Austria" }selected="selected" {/if}>Austria</option>
    <option value="Bahamas" {if country=="Bahamas" }selected="selected" {/if}>Bahamas</option>
    <option value="Belgium" {if country=="Belgium" }selected="selected" {/if}>Belgium</option>
    <option value="Canada" {if country=="Canada" }selected="selected" {/if}>Canada</option>
    .....
    <option value="United States" {if country=="United States" }selected="selected" {/if}>United States</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="rest1">
  Div 1 content
</div>
<div class="rest2">
  Div 2 content
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you add some representative HTML in order that we can easily reproduce the problem, and give you an answer tailored to your specific problem?

Comment: Is this a multi-select? What should it do if they select both `United States` and `Austria`? If it's not a multi-select, why are you looping? There's just one value, which you get with `$(this).val()`.

Comment: Barmar - This is not multi-select. But I don't know what you mean about looping. I'm not very experienced with jquery.

Comment: David Thomas - I added more html to the original post. Thanks for looking.

Comment: `{if ...}` is not HTML.

Comment: `checked` is not a valid attribute for `<select>`.

Comment: Your code seems to work when I try it.

Comment: `.each()` is a loop. What else could I have been referring to?

Comment: If you want someone to see your comment, you have to put `@` before their name, e.g. @Barmar. David Thomas doesn't know you tried to message him.

Comment: Your current code translates to *"every time the select element changes, loop over every option and if any option contains 'united states' then show/hide some elements, also it any item contains anything that is not 'united states' then show/hide some items"* - Eventually this does too much work (no loop is needed) and everything cancels itself out.  The Below answer by @Barmar is a much improved version of what you are trying to do

Comment: @ChrisBarr They're not looping over every option, only the `:selected` one. That's why it *should* work unless it's a multi-select.

Comment: @Barmar Ah yes, you're right, I missed that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop over the options. Just get the value of the select and compare it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'United States') {
      $(".rest1").show();
      $(".rest2").hide();
    } else {
      $(".rest2").show();
      $(".rest1").hide();
    }
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.rest1,
.rest2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="country" class="form-label">Country <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
  <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="rest1">
  Div 1 content
</div>
<div class="rest2">
  Div 2 content
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean about the loop now. Just what I needed.